# SQL multiple REPLACE cases

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a transaction reference table with *varchar* Transaction Identifiers in a MSSQL DB.

```
eg. 20121018A436712SF2CPMQ7177
```

But in some transactions, there is some noise in the form of **special identifiers** such as

```
1114
1160
H600
....
....
etc
```

I was thinking of using *REPLACE* statement to replace them like

```
select REPLACE (identifier, '%1114%', '') from Transactions
```

but I don't know how to do *REPLACE* using all these conditions.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would build a table of "special identifiers" and populate it, e.g.

```
create table special_identifiers (
   id int identity not null primary key clustered,
   key varchar(10) not null unique
);
```

You would then perform your removal of these special ids like this in a SELECT

```
    SELECT i.col1, i.col2,
           CASE WHEN si.key IS NOT NULL then '' ELSE i.identifier END identifier
      FROM Transactions i
 LEFT JOIN special_identifiers si on si.key = i.identifier
```

This can be easily expanded if you really need to use a LIKE, such as 'xxx' anywhere in an id should remove it, e.g.

```
 LEFT JOIN special_identifiers si on i.identifier LIKE '%' + si.key + '%'
```

Although I would just add the %'s into the `key` column itself for greater flexibility.

Finally, if you simply cannot persist the table, you can always virtually make it up, e.g.

```
    SELECT i.col1, i.col2,
           CASE WHEN si.key IS NOT NULL then '' ELSE i.identifier END identifier
      FROM Transactions i
 LEFT JOIN (select '1114' key UNION ALL
            select '1160') si on si.key = i.identifier
```

Comment: Thanks, does what I was after (with some tweaking)

Answer (score 0):

If you `Transaction identifier` is a fixed length string, say 12 characters, you can select the right most 12 characters as;

```
SELECT RIGHT(identifier_column,12)
```

Comment: I will keep that technique in mind, but in the current scenario the noise can be embedded anywhere in the transaction, not specifically the right hand side